# how do you set the jquery tabs to form a 100% height?

Tags: jquery, tabs, height

how do you set the jquery tabs to form a 100% height?

i also need to resize the iframe within it to expand to 100% height.

thank you!

Comment: some code would make it easier to see what's going on...CSS and HTML markup of the elements discussed.

Answer (score 6):

To resize the UI Tabs (latest 1.7.2 version, at least), it worked with the following code:

```
$ (document).ready (function () {
function resizeUi() {
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();
    $("#tabs").css('height', h-95 );
    $(".ui-tabs-panel").css('height', h-140 );
};

var resizeTimer = null;
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    if (resizeTimer) clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(resizeUi, 100);
});
resizeUi();
}
```

Plus the flollowing css:

```
#tabs { 
    display: inline-block; 
    width:325px;
}
```

You wil have to edit some numbers according to you needs.

Comment: Forgot about the IFRAME. Just add this line $("iframe#myiframe").css('height', h-95 ); at the end of the function above, and tweak the "95" value. could be 0 in you case.

Answer (score 3):

If ever it can be of any use to someone else, I added some callbacks to "show" and "add" in order to always get a perfect height. In my case the top container has the class "ui-layout-pane" (as I use jquery layouts), but that should work with any class.

```
myTab = $("#tabs").tabs({
    show: function(e,ui){
        var $c = $(ui.panel), h = parseInt($(ui.tab).parent().outerHeight());
        while ( $c.length > 0 && !$c.hasClass("ui-layout-pane") ){
            h += ( $c.outerHeight(true) - $c.innerHeight() );
            $c = $c.parent();
        }
        h = parseInt($c.innerHeight() - h );
        $(ui.panel).height(h);
        return true;
    },
    add: function(e,ui){
        $(this).tabs("select",ui.index);
    }
});
```

Comment: In the 'show' event, I had to change `$(ui.panel).height(h);` to `$(ui.panel).parent().height(h);` and it worked!  JQuery UI v1.8.14.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it reliably (cross browser) with just css.

Maybe you should use jquery to get the height of the page and set each element like that:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   var wh = parseInt($(window).height());

   if ($.browser.opera) {
      wh = $.browser.version > "9.5" ? document.documentElement["clientHeight"] : wh;
   }

   $('#elementid').css("height", wh);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a div with height:100% to have the tab contents expand to cover the whole screen height.

For iframe resizing see [here](http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing).

Comment: already did the 100% height on all html, body, & div. but still im in no luck.

the iframe trick also didn't work. any other suggestions?

Comment: btw, im generating the iframe via .html()

Answer (score -3):

have you tried try setting height property using CSS method:

```
$("#ID OF YOUR TAB ELEMENT").css("height","100%");
```